# PHPのPATH通す、今はどういう状態？

Tags: php, macos, bash, command-line, mamp

PHPのPATHを通したく、ネットの参考を手順通り進めたら、

```
$ which php
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php
$ php -v
PHP 5.4.10 (cli) (built: ...tec.
```

と、成功をしたものの、もう一度確認をしたら、

```
$ which php … 反応なし
$ php -v … command not found
```

と出ます。
今はどういう状態でしょうか？
どういう風に修正すればよろしいでしょうか？

```
cat ~/.bash_profile
```

反応なし

```
cat ~/.bashrc
cat: /Users/youtenyu/.bashrc: No such file or directory
```

と出ます。

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin 
exec $SHELL -l 
which php 
php -v 
bash: php: command not found
```

この順番に入れていき、最後に`bash: php: command not found`が出てきました。

Comment: 参考にしたサイトのURLは覚えていますか？

Comment: unaristさんコメントありがとうございます!!
http://webkaru.net/php/mamp-php-bin-path/
こちらでございます！

Comment: http://www.starlod.net/mac-os-x-10-11-ei-capitan-operation-not-permitted.html
途中でOperation not permittedが出ましたので、こちらも実行しました。

Comment: `echo $PATH` の結果はどうなってますか？

Comment: ernixさんありがとうございます>_<
'/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin'
と出ました。正直どういう意味かわからないです…

Comment: いくつか考えられます。1.大前提としてbashを使っている必要があります。`echo $SHELL`はbashですか？ 2. 手順通り`~/.bash_profile`にexportを書いていなかった可能性があります。もしくはファイル名が間違っているか。3. 現在のシェルがログインシェルでないせいで`~/.bash_profile`が読みこまれなかった可能性があります。`shopt -q login_shell && echo $?`の結果は"0"ですか？またはTerminal.appを新規に開いたら`which php`の結果は変わりますか？

Comment: echo $SHELL → /bin/bash  /////

    bash_profile → -bash: bash_profile: command not found  /////

    shopt -q login_shell && echo $? → 0 /////

    which php → 何度試しても反応がないです  

(指示と違うことをやっていたらすいません）

Comment: `cat ~/.bash_profile` と `cat ~/.bashrc` の結果を質問に追加してみてもらえますか？別のところで$PATHを上書きしているのかも。

Comment: ビンゴです。~/.bash_profileがカラになってます。ログイン時に$PATHが有効になるように、ファイルの中でexportしないといけません。

Answer (score 1):

PATHは環境変数と呼ばれるもので、シェルプログラム bash は環境変数PATHに設定したディレクトリからコマンドを探します。

> 今はどういう状態でしょうか？

`export` は環境変数を設定するためのコマンドですが、シェルプログラムを終了すると `export` で変更した内容は破棄されます。
そのため `php -v` を実行しても シェルプログラムは `php` コマンドを発見することができず `command not found` というエラーを表示しているのではと思います。

> どういう風に修正すればよろしいでしょうか？

`~/.bash_profile` ファイルに `export PATH=...` コマンドを記述することで ログイン（もしくはターミナルを開く）のたびに `export` コマンドが実行されます。

`~/.bash_profile` に記述する例

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile        ←ファイルが空なので何も表示されない
$ echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin" >> ~/.bash_profile
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin     ←ファイルに追記されたことを確認
```

確認のため `~/.bash_profile` を読み込みます。

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin  ←読み込む前の 環境変数PATHの値を表示
$ . ~/.bash_profile
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin   ←環境変数PATH にディレクトリが追加された
```

末尾に `:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin` が追加されていれば成功です。

ターミナルを新しく開くと自動的に `~/.bash_profile` が読み込まれるため、PATH の内容が変更されてることが確認出来るはずです。

```
Last login: Thu Dec 10 13:48:24 on ttys002
mymac:~ take88$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin   ←自動的に PATH が変更されたことを確認
```

Comment: 大変丁寧に教えていただきありがとうございます!無事末尾に :/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin を追加することが出来ました!しかしPHPバージョンが間違っていることに気付きました…なので手順としては、これを一回消してから、もう一度同じ手順で正解の方のPHPバージョンを入れたらいいのでしょうか？だとしたら消し方も教えていただきたいです。宜しくお願いします。私のミスで申し訳ありません。

Comment: ファイルを記述するコマンドの「>>」のところを「>」にすると上書きすることができます。2個だと追記で1個だと上書きです。

Comment: takeさん出来ました、これからPHPバージョンアップしてもやり方がわかりましたので安心です。本当にありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

http://webkaru.net/php/mamp-php-bin-path/

にある手順をもう一度確認してください。

`~/.bash_profile`に以下の内容を追記する必要があります。

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin
```

ちなみに上のURLではその後`source ~/.bash_profile`しろとありますが、`exec $SHELL -l` の方がいいかと思います。

Comment: 助けてもらって本当にありがとうございます!!!  
    
    'export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin
    exec $SHELL -l
    which php
    php -v
    bash: php: command not found'  
    
この順番でこう出ました…
すいません、どこが違うかご指摘お願いします。

Comment: 何をした時にそういう出力になりました？

Comment: 質問文に追加させていただきました。これしかしていません。

Comment: `~/.bash_profile`に入れるのは、`export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin`だけです。他のコマンドは入れなくていいです。

Comment: 大変すいません、私のやり方が間違っているのだと思います…もう一度教えていただきたいです(おじぎ)
最初に
    'export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin'
    入力後、~/.bash_profileを入力、であっていますか？

Comment: はい。その前に`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php -v`を実行してみて下さい。バージョンが表示されるようであれば`~/.bash_profile`に追記します。コマンドライン上でファイルの読み書きをされたことはありますか？Finderはデフォルトでドット"."から始まるファイルが非表示になっているので、デスクトップから".bash_profile"を作成することはできません。コマンドライン上で作成する必要があります。

Comment: お疲れ様です!!実行しましたが、
    -bash: Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php: No such file or directory  と出ました。
'bash_profile'は以前作成しました、今日も'ls -aで確認しましたが、ありました。
これはあるけど、壊れているということでしょうか？宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: もう一度確認してください。エラーはコマンド実行時に最初のスラッシュ"/"が入っていないことを示しています。`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php -v`です。最初のスラッシュが抜けていませんか？

Comment: '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php -v
-bash: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php: No such file or directory'  
私も忘れてたんだと思ってもう一度やり直しましたが、同じです…

Comment: `ls -ald /Applications/MAMP` は結果が出力されますか？されてなければMAMP自体入ってない気がします。

Comment: drwxrwxr-x@ 22 "my name"  admin  748 11 29 09:28 /Applications/MAMPって出ました!どういう意味でしょうか??

Comment: MANPのディレクトリが存在するか確認しました。MANPは入っているようなので、phpのバージョンが参照したページとは違うのかなと思います。その下のディレクトリはどうなってますか？

Comment: そうですね…もう一度MAMPのPHPファイルを確認したらphp5.6.10でした。これは完全に最初から間違っているから可笑しいなことになっていたのでしょうか？気付かせていただきありがとうございます。直したいです。

Comment: ernixさん無事出来ました。間違いを気付かせていただきありがとうございます！